# ElasticSearch6.8: Unassigned Shards

Tags: elasticsearch

my elasticsearch has some unassigned shards.
I used below command to find it as below shown
The reason for unassigned shard  is  INDEX_CREATION at replica node, what doe it mean?
my elasticsearch is running on single machine , single node cluster.
Could I just simply delete this unassigned shard? will it be data loss problem?

thank you in advance

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/_cat/shards?h=index,shards,state,prirep,unassigned.reason | grep UNASSIGNED
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 31005  100 31005    0     0  1081k     filebeat-6.8.22-<MY_APP_NAME>-2023.06.28                    UNASSIGNED r INDEX_CREATED
```

#### result with `curl -XGET localhost:9200/_cluster/allocation/explain`

```
{
  "index": "filebeat-6.8.22-xxx-2023.06.28",
  "shard": 2,
  "primary": false,
  "current_state": "unassigned",
  "unassigned_info": {
    "reason": "INDEX_CREATED",
    "at": "2023-06-27T22:30:57.674Z",
    "last_allocation_status": "no_attempt"
  },
  "can_allocate": "no",
  "allocate_explanation": "cannot allocate because allocation is not permitted to any of the nodes",
  "node_allocation_decisions": [
    {
      "node_id": "Uhqplef-S3mJRdDIonSGPw",
      "node_name": "Uhqplef",
      "transport_address": "x.x.x.x:9300",
      "node_attributes": {
        "ml.machine_memory": "37665476608",
        "xpack.installed": "true",
        "ml.max_open_jobs": "20",
        "ml.enabled": "true"
      },
      "node_decision": "no",
      "weight_ranking": 1,
      "deciders": [
        {
          "decider": "same_shard",
          "decision": "NO",
          "explanation": "the shard cannot be allocated to the same node on which a copy of the shard already exists [[filebeat-6.8.22-xxx-2023.06.28][2], node[Uhqplef-S3mJRdDIonSGPw], [P], s[STARTED], a[id=Gh6Wxo0QROC_x68MNPq1TQ]]"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a single data node and your index has a primary and a replica shard, the replica cannot be allocated to any node as a primary and replica shard cannot be allocated to the same node.

You can simply remove the replica like this:

```
PUT filebeat-*/_settings
{
  "index.number_of_replicas": 0
}
```

If you have an index template for your filebeat indexes, you can also make the modification in the index template so that new indexes are created without replica shard.

Comment: thanks all for quick reply,  do I just need to remove replica and delete unassgined shard
or just remove replica ?

Comment: replica shard == unassigned shard, it's the same thing. Just run the command above and the replica shard will be removed and your cluster will be green without any unassigned shard.

Comment: yes, it works like charm, you are hero !